# CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I build an android project which includes ndk code. I got the following error:

```
Build command failed. 
Error while executing process /home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app -B/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=} 
/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo 
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
Build command failed. 
Error while executing process /home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app -B/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=} 
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I try to locate the cause.

I found the following:

```
gongzelong@gongzelong:~/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin$ cmake -version
CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.5
cmake version 3.5.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

It seems that the cmake has separately versions 3.5 and 3.6.

Could anyone point out how to fix it and build the android project successfully?

Update:

I delete the cmake and install it again in android studio sdk manager.

I still got this:

```
null    
Build command failed.   
Error while executing process /home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app -B/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=}    
/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo    
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage   
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
Build command failed.   
Error while executing process /home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app -B/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/media/gongzelong/TOSHIBA/Code/Code/ImageLoaderEncapsulation/ImageLoader/ImageLoaderDemo/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/gongzelong/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=}  
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage   
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: did you updated the NDK?

Comment: @E.Abdel I open the sdk manager in Android studio, it only has one version 3.6.4111459. What do you say about updating the ndk?

Comment: Do you have an update available for cmake? seems like an update that was borken, in my case I have /Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6 instead of 3.5, so if you have an update available so updated else remove it an install it again via sdk manager

Comment: @E.Abdel I delete it and install it again. Yes, I also have Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/share/cmake-3.6, but still got the same error

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like you are using an NDK version that is no more supporting some ABIs (armeabi in you error log), so you have to upgrade build in **build.gradle (Project:....)**  to the latest one

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'`

And in **gradle-wraper.properties** : `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

And finally, you have to add **abiFilters** in android block of your **build.gradle(Module:app)** depending of wich ABIs you need:

```
android {
 ....
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            }
        }
    }
 ....
}
```

Comment: After updating gradle plugin and gradle wrapper version, it works. Thanks. It seems that I do not need to add abiFilters.

Comment: "externalNativeBuild" helped, while updating gradle-4.x version does not help in my case. Thanks!

Comment: externalNativeBuild" helped me . Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 9):

In my case, following changes in build.gradle (Module:app ) help me.

Original

```
android {
 ....
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static' ... [other args]
            }
        }
    }
 ....
}
```

With my changes

```
android {
 android.buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
 ....
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static' ... [other args]
            }
        }
    }
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the same error, and my ndk-bundle is the newest, which is ndk-r18b

```
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I fix it by use android-ndk-r14b, you can specify it in `local.properties`

```
ndk.dir=/Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/android-ndk-r14b
```

Of course, you should download r14b first, and unzip it under the sdk folder

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstall and reinstall the NDK from SDK tools. This works for me.