# Issue with "CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set", but cannot update environment

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I know similar questions have been asked, but none that fit my problem exactly.

I am working on an android project, using Android Studio. I am adding a C++ library to the existing project.

Here is my problem : When I attempt to compile, I receive this error message :

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process /home/v/opt/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/home/v/proj/code/android/cppmanager -B/home/v/proj/code/android/tooltipgenerator/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/v/opt/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/android/tooltipgenerator/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/v/opt/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/v/opt/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16}


 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
Open File


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

When I click on "Open file" it opens `ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake` to line 312.

```
# ABI.
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI ${ANDROID_ABI})
if(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL armeabi-v7a)
  set(ANDROID_SYSROOT_ABI arm)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME arm-linux-androideabi)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT ${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME})
  set(ANDROID_HEADER_TRIPLE arm-linux-androideabi)
  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR armv7-a)
  set(ANDROID_LLVM_TRIPLE armv7-none-linux-androideabi)
elseif(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL arm64-v8a)
  set(ANDROID_SYSROOT_ABI arm64)
  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME aarch64-linux-android)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT ${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME})
  set(ANDROID_LLVM_TRIPLE aarch64-none-linux-android)
  set(ANDROID_HEADER_TRIPLE aarch64-linux-android)
elseif(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL x86)
  set(ANDROID_SYSROOT_ABI x86)
  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR i686)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME i686-linux-android)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT ${ANDROID_ABI})
  set(ANDROID_LLVM_TRIPLE i686-none-linux-android)
  set(ANDROID_HEADER_TRIPLE i686-linux-android)
elseif(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL x86_64)
  set(ANDROID_SYSROOT_ABI x86_64)
  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME x86_64-linux-android)
  set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT ${ANDROID_ABI})
  set(ANDROID_LLVM_TRIPLE x86_64-none-linux-android)
  set(ANDROID_HEADER_TRIPLE x86_64-linux-android)
else()
  set(ANDROID_ABI_ERROR "")
  if(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL armeabi)
    set(ANDROID_ABI_ERROR " (armeabi is no longer supported. Use armeabi-v7a.)")
  elseif(ANDROID_ABI MATCHES "^(mips|mips64)$")
    set(ANDROID_ABI_ERROR " (MIPS and MIPS64 are no longer supported.)")
  endif() // line 312
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Invalid Android ABI: ${ANDROID_ABI}.${ANDROID_ABI_ERROR}")
endif()
```

Other questions/answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50759336/8154557) suggest updating  gradle. I have also found suggestions to update the SDK, the NDK... which seems like a good idea, except this would break my existing project.

I am running Android Studio 3.1.3, and Gradle 2.3.3

Here is an extract from my main build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.proj"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 82
        versionName "b-1.5.2"
        multiDexEnabled = true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can solve this issue without upgrading my build environment ?

I have already payed around a bit with abiFilters, with no success... but maybe I just played around wrong ?

I have also already tried updating gradle, but it did not fix anything and instead broke the rest of the project.

I have been racking my brain for quite a while now, so any suggestion would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: The error saying that you are using ABIs that are no more supported : if(ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL **armeabi**)
    set(ANDROID_ABI_ERROR " (**armeabi** is no longer supported. Use **armeabi-v7a.**)")..., in your abiFilters, get ride of mips and armeabi and try to compile.

Comment: Thank you. However, I still get the same issue. Note that the error still says it comes from armeabi even when I removed it from the abiFilters list...

Comment: You use cmake wich is an external build tool, so try by changing the `ndk{....}` block `by defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {....}}`